# Помогите решить ошибку

Tags: python, aiogram

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = 'тут мой токен бота'

# инициализация бота
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

# обработка команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Товары", callback_data='products'),
                 types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поддержка", callback_data='support'))

    await message.answer("Привет! Я бот для оплаты. Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)

# обработка нажатий на inline кнопки
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'products')
async def process_products(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ключ майн", callback_data='buy_key'))

    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Список товаров:", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'buy_key')
async def process_buy_key(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Плати")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ошибка

```
line 3, in <module> from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.contrib' –
```

Comment: Какую ошибку???

Comment: line 3, in <module>
    from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.contrib'

Comment: Смысл ошибки понятен?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас установлена версия aiogram3.0 или выше, а в этих версиях есть существенные отличия. Установите версию 2.9 или ниже и все скорее всего все заработает. Например

```
pip install aiogram<2.9
```

если пользуетесь pip.